# React call a function from other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm doing a simple CRUD with ReactJS.

I want to add a new Hero to a list of Heroes in class HeroModel. However I don't know how to call the function AddHero in HeroModel.js from AddHero.js.

Here is my code:

HeroModel.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HeroModel {

state = {
    Heroes: [
        { Id: 1, Name: "hero1", Dob: new Date("1-1-2017"), Stocked: true, Price: 1.50 },
        { Id: 2, Name: "hero2", Dob: new Date("5-31-2018"), Stocked: false, Price: 2.50 },
        { Id: 3, Name: "hero3", Dob: new Date("2019"), Stocked: true, Price: 3.50 },
        { Id: 4, Name: "hero4", Dob: new Date("4-20-2010"), Stocked: false, Price: 4.50 },
        { Id: 5, Name: "hero5", Dob: new Date("12-31-2018"), Stocked: true, Price: 5.50 },
    ]
}

GetAllHeroes() {
    return this.state.Heroes;
}

AddHero(name, dob, stocked, price) {
    let id = this.state.Heroes.length + 1;
    this.state.Heroes = [...this.state.Heroes,
    { Id: id, Name: name, Dob: dob, Stocked: stocked, Price: price }];
    }
}

export default HeroModel;
```

AddHero.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HeroModel from './HeroModel';

class AddHero extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        Id: 0, Name: "", Dob: new Date(), Stocked: true, Price: 0
    };

}

onNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        Name: e.target.value
    });
}

onDobChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        Dob: e.target.value
    });
}

onStockedChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        Stocked : e.target.value
    });
}

onPriceChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        Price : e.target.value
    });
}

onSave(e){
//----I get stuck here-----
//    (new HeroModel).AddHero(
//        this.state.Name, this.state.Dob, 
//        this.state.Stocked, this.state.Price);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Add hero</h1>
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Name </label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.onNameChange.bind(this)}></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Dob </label>
                    <input type="date" onChange={this.onDobChange.bind(this)} defaultValue={new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)}></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Stocked </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onStockedChange.bind(this)} ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Price </label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.onPriceChange.bind(this)}></input>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.onSave.bind(this)}>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default AddHero;
```

Please help me to add a new Hero to a list of Heroes in HeroMode.js. 
I comment in function onSave(e) where I get stuck.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you write code please indent it correctly it will be easier to read for you and for others.

Comment: Not sure, but if you have single instance outside of AddHero, then you need to pass that object to your AddHero component as prop or add it as function prop and call that prop. or you can use it outside `var heroModel = new HeroModel()` (just after import) and use it in component.

Comment: Your class `HeroModel` isn't a `React` component. Useless import.

Comment: Why are you creating HeroModel.js as a React Component, this can be achieved by simple HeroModel Class.

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma, will do. I'm new to React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit, for redux implementation, see this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-reactredux-flow-l9oq4

To call a function defined in another function, you need to pass it down as a property. This creates a Parent-Child relationship.

Let's consider the following:

1. Your Parent-component holds the list of `Heroes` in its state.
2. Your Parent-component has a function that lets you add more heroes.
   We will call it `createNewHero()`
3. Your Parent-component passes `createNewHero()` down as a prop to the
   child, `AddHero`
4. `AddHero` holds input data in its `state`, we will pass that data as an object to the prop, `createNewHero()`. Effectively passing the data upwards.
5. When`createNewHero()` is called, its execution context is bound to
   the parent component. So when `this.setState()` is executed, the keyword, `this` points to `HeroModel's` state.
6. When complete, we add a single `Hero` to the list, thus changing the
   state, causing our component to re-render.

Checkout the following sandbox to see this in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dawn-l9oq4

### HeroModel (Parent)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AddHero from "./AddHero";

import "./styles.css";

class HeroModel extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Heroes: [
      {
        Id: 1,
        Name: "hero1",
        Dob: new Date("1-1-2017"),
        Stocked: true,
        Price: 1.5
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        Name: "hero2",
        Dob: new Date("5-31-2018"),
        Stocked: false,
        Price: 2.5
      },
      {
        Id: 3,
        Name: "hero3",
        Dob: new Date("2019"),
        Stocked: true,
        Price: 3.5
      },
      {
        Id: 4,
        Name: "hero4",
        Dob: new Date("4-20-2010"),
        Stocked: false,
        Price: 4.5
      },
      {
        Id: 5,
        Name: "hero5",
        Dob: new Date("12-31-2018"),
        Stocked: true,
        Price: 5.5
      }
    ]
  };

  createNewHero = newHero => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      Heroes: [...this.state.Heroes, newHero]
    });
  };

  renderHeros = () => {
    const { Heroes } = this.state;

    return Heroes.map(hero => {
      return <div>{hero.Name}</div>;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderHeros()}
        <AddHero createNewHero={this.createNewHero} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default HeroModel;
```

### AddHero (Child)

```
import React from "react";

class AddHero extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Id: 0,
      Name: "",
      Dob: new Date(),
      Stocked: true,
      Price: 0
    };
  }

  onSave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { Id, Name, Stocked, Price } = this.state;
    const newHero = {
      Id: Id,
      Name: Name,
      Dob: new Date(),
      Stocked: Stocked,
      Price: Price
    };

    this.props.createNewHero(newHero);
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add hero</h1>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Name </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} name="Name" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Dob </label>
            <input
              type="date"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              defaultValue={new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)}
              name="Dob"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Stocked </label>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange} name="Stocked" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Price </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} name="Price" />
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.onSave}>Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddHero;
```

Comment: I want to create a new component AllHeroes.js to display all Heroes from HeroModel.js. But this component is separate from AddHero, I don't want them to display in one page. So what is the solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I got an error on this line this.props.createNewHero(newHero);
TypeError: this.props.createNewHero is not a function

Comment: @anhtv13 Hi, I just saw your comment. If you would like to create a new hero in one component and have it available in another component without them being on the same page, you'll have to integrate something like Redux, which is a global store/data container. That is an entirely new problem altogether, but I can probably whip up something real quick.

Comment: @anhtv13, I created a sandbox for you to see how you would be able to achieve this functionality with redux. Let me know if you have any questions. https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-reactredux-flow-l9oq4

Comment: Thanks Chris, I really appreciate your efforts

Comment: @anhtv13 you're very welcome! I really hope that my updated sandbox is helpful to you. If you have any questions, I'd be glad to help. Also, if you find that it's exactly what you're looking for, please consider marking my solution as the answer. :)